# Is there a Google Wave desktop notifier for Linux/Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, google-wave, notify-osd

Is there a Google Wave desktop notifier for Linux/Ubuntu?

One integrated with OSD Notify would be great... or a taskbar notifier would be sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of now it seems there's no Google Wave Desktop notifier, as a native app for Linux. There is one, however

- [As a Firefox addon](http://thatsmith.com/2009/10/google-wave-add-on-for-firefox)
- [A Windows program which runs fine using WINE](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wave-notify/files/)
- [An Adobe AIR application](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/marketplace/index.cfm?event=marketplace.offering&offeringid=16581)

Answer (score 1):

[Also a Chrome extension is available](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/aphncaagnlabkeipnbbicmcahnamibgb)